# Как подключиться к DB SQLite через Database Navigator от Jetbrains?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

В приложении пользуюсь SQLite и вот хочу с помощью Database Navigator

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator

Но я не могу подключиться

---

Что я делаю:

1) Установил плагин (Database Navigator)

2) Открываю вкладку DB browser

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Потом нажимаю на тот плюс в левом верхнем углу, выбираю SQLite и открывается окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот вопрос: что нужно тут указать? Есть ли у кого то мануал или что то такое? как этим вообще пользоваться...

Для чего мне это нужно: мне нужно посмотреть как идут записи в таблицу

Так как в какой то момент данные в таблице меняются на другие

Если нажимаю на кнопку `Test connection`, то появляется такой popup

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите кто с этим работал, как сделать настройки, чтоб подключиться к DB?

Comment: Кликнуть в ячейку `Database files` и выбрать, предварительно скопированный на десктоп, файл БД.

Comment: @woesss если я правильно понимаю, то этот плагин не дает доступа в реальном времени? Мне нужно вытянуть этот файл и только потом к нему подключаться?